# Sitecore Powershell SPE 5.1 "Could not validate access using the provided credentials" error

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have written the SPE powershell script in my local **Sitecore 9.1.1** sandbox environment and trying to execute, it is asking session elevate privilege to enter credentials. Even though I am entering admin credentials I am getting "***Could not validate access using the provided credentials***" error.

> 1. I have verified Cognifide.PowerShell.config is present.
> 2. I have enabled the Cognifide.PowerShell.IdentityServer.config since I am using Identity server
> 3. SPE version 5.1 which is compatible with Sitecore 9.1.1

[image]

Comment: Where are you hosting it?

Comment: Did you implement a custom provider or using Azure AD?

Comment: It is in my local sandbox which is installed in my laptop. I am using default "admin" login

Comment: @PrabhuRanganathan Did you find a fix for this issue? we are facing the same issue.

Comment: @Bala - I changed the elevationAction="Allow" for the required tokens under  <userAccountControl><tokens> from Cognifide.PowerShell.config to make it work. I am not sure this is the solution for this since this is related to some permission issue. But it worked for me.

Comment: @PrabhuRanganathan - I have the same issue and your suggestion was very helpful. My local PC is where I had the issue. While not the ideal solution I am the only one working on that computer.

Comment: I have seen this issue when the admin (or any password) is hashed differently on the identity server vs the server you are pointed to.  The default oob hash is sha1 but we updated ours to sha512 and this broke peoples ability to elevate session but they could still log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the below config

```
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
        <powershell>
            <userAccountControl>
                <tokens>
                    <token name="ISE" set:expiration="00:05:00" set:elevationAction="Allow"/>
                </tokens>
            </userAccountControl>
        </powershell>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

To assure this config file will be loaded after the SPE.config file name it zzz.MyConfig.config.
Sitecore loads .configs file in alphabetical sort order so this might solve the issue.

You can also use patch:instead directive like below, but it still has to be loaded after SPE.config file, otherwise your configs will be replaced.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <powershell>
            <userAccountControl>
                <tokens>
                    <token name="ISE" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Allow" patch:instead="*[@name='ISE']"/>
                </tokens>
            </userAccountControl>
        </powershell>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**P.S. The configs that are declared in Layers.config file will be loaded first.
For instance, let's say you are working in a helix based solution and you have this code block in your Layers.config file.**

```
<layer name="Custom" includeFolder="/App_Config/Include/">
  <loadOrder>
    <add path="Foundation" type="Folder" />
    <add path="Feature" type="Folder" />
    <add path="Project" type="Folder" />
  </loadOrder>
</layer>
```

**So that, if you are creating your config under Foundation folder and the SPE.config file is not declared in Layers.config file, your config file will be loaded first and the SPE.config file will replace your configuration.**

***References***

https://mskutta.github.io/2017/08/09/sitecore-patchinstead-in-config/

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/using-patch-files-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-patch-file-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html

https://sitecorepowershell.com/session-state-elevation/